# Which PATH does `sudo <command>` use to search for `<command>`?

Tags: sudo, path

I installed eclipse in my home directory, and put its path in `PATH` in `~/.profile`.

So it works by

```
$ eclipse
```

But when call it with `sudo`, `eclipse` isn't found:

```
$ sudo eclipse 
sudo: eclipse: command not found
```

Which `PATH` does `sudo eclipse` use to search for `eclipse`? Is it the user `root`'s `PATH`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo` by default uses a *minimal* `PATH`, to make it safe for use by the *root* user.  That is not necessarily the same as the `PATH` you would get by logging in as the *root* user, or by doing

```
sudo su -
```

For instance, in newer Red Hat releases, I've noticed that the path omits `/usr/local/bin`.

The manual page summarizes this in a section entitled [*Security Notes*](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html):

> sudo tries to be safe when executing external commands.
>
> There are two distinct ways to deal with environment variables.  By default, the **`env_reset`** sudoers
>   option is enabled.  This causes commands to be executed with a minimal environment containing **`TERM`**,
>   **`PATH`**, **`HOME`**, **`SHELL`**, **`LOGNAME`**, **`USER`** and **`USERNAME`** in addition to variables from the invoking process
>   permitted by the `env_check` and `env_keep` sudoers options.  There is effectively a whitelist for
>   environment variables.

Further reading:

- [sudoers - list of which users may execute what](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sudoers.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/sudoers)

  > **`secure_path`**
  >   Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don't trust the people running sudo to
  >   have a sane PATH environment variable you may want to use this.  Another use is if you
  >   want to have the "root path" be separate from the "user path."  Users in the group
  >   specified by the **`exempt_group`** option are not affected by **`secure_path`**.  This option is not
  >   set by default.
- [sudo - execute a command as another user](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html)

Comment: Thanks.  Wonder why linux doesn't have a manpage for `sudo`. see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_1.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_8.html

Comment: 1. How can I get and set the values of the `PATH` used by `sudo`? 2. Is it correct that its `PATH` is not used by any other user including `root`?