# Have a command in my $PATH, but it is not being recognized when I use sudo

Tags: sudo, root, path, profile

I’m using Ubuntu 14.04.  I’m having trouble getting a command picked up in my $PATH using sudo.  I have added this to my /root/.profile file

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/default/bin

mesg n
```

I have logged out and logged back in as my user with sudo privileges.  Then I try and run the command within the $PATH but I get a “command not found” …

```
daveuser@mymachine:/home/rails/myproject$ sudo gem pristine --all
sudo: gem: command not found
daveuser@mymachine:/home/rails/myproject$ sudo echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/    bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin
daveuser@mymachine:/home/rails/myproject$ sudo which gem
daveuser@mymachine:/home/rails/myproject$ which gem
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/gem
```

Notice that when I echo $PATH I get exactly the PATH where the “gem” command lives.  What else do I need to do to get my “gem” command recognized when I run the command as the sudo user?

**Edit:** The preserve-env didn’t work.  here’s what happened …

```
remoteuser@remotemachine:/home/rails/myproject$ sudo --preserve-env gem pristine --all
[sudo] password for remoteuser: 
sudo: gem: command not found
```

**Edit 2:** output of sudo -l

```
remoteuser@rtemotemachine:/home/rails/myproject$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for remoteuser on rtemotemachine:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User remoteuser may run the following commands on rtemotemachine:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Related: [Which PATH does `sudo <command>` use to search for `<command>`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294126/which-path-does-sudo-command-use-to-search-for-command)

Comment: Notice also that when you do `sudo echo $PATH`, the shell expands `$PATH` before `sudo` ever comes into play. Also, please add the output of `sudo -l`.

Comment: @muru, edited question to include "sudo -l" output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default sudo resets environment variables for security reasons, check for following line in /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults    env_reset
```

PATH variable is reset to "secure_path" value .

```
e.g. Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

You can try

`sudo env "PATH=$PATH" [command]` to preserve path of sudo -E didn't work.

A better explanation can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91541/why-is-path-reset-in-a-sudo-command)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
sudo --preserve-env
```

> -E, --preserve-env 
>   Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve
>   their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return
>   an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the
>   environment.

Comment: I still got a command not found when I ran that.  I included teh output in my question.