# '-bash: line 1: rescanscsi: command not found' error even though script location is in PATH and other script runs fine from same folder

Tags: bash, shell, path, command-not-found

I'm new to linux, trying to switch over from Windows, and I could really use some help.  This is actually my first time using a forum such as this so please forgive any errors I make.

I'm using Linux Mint XFCE 64-bit and I have two scripts located in /usr/local/bin/custom, as can be seen as follows:

```shellsession
dasaint@X1:~$ which load-ssh-keys
/usr/local/bin/custom/load-ssh-keys

dasaint@X1:~$ which rescanscsi
/usr/local/bin/custom/rescanscsi

dasaint@X1:~$ whereis rescanscsi
rescanscsi: /usr/local/bin/custom/rescanscsi

dasaint@X1:~$ whereis load-ssh-keys
load-ssh-keys: /usr/local/bin/custom/load-ssh-keys
```

`/usr/local/bin/custom` is in my global path, as has been set in `/etc/environment`

```shellsession
dasaint@X1:~$ echo $PATH
/home/dasaint/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/custom:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Yet when I run `rescanscsi`, I get the following error:

```shellsession
dasaint@X1:~$ sudo rescanscsi
sudo: rescanscsi: command not found
```

The strange thing is, if I run sudo `/usr/local/bin/custom/rescanscsi` it works just fine.

And if I run the other script, `load-ssh-keys`, without specifying the absolute path, it also works just fine.  The contents of the scripts are:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/bash
#
# /usr/local/bin/custom/rescanscsi
#
# ReScan all SCSI/SATA Hosts
#
for SHOST in /sys/class/scsi_host/host*; do
    echo -n "Scanning ${SHOST##*/}..."
    echo "- - -" > ${SHOST}/scan
    echo Done
done
```

and

```bash
#! /usr/bin/bash
#
# Script:       load-ssh-keys.sh
# path:         /usr/local/bin/scripts
# Purpose:      add SSH private keys into ssh-agent
# Dependencies: '/usr/bin/expect'
#               '/usr/bin/ssh-add'
# 
# '/usr/bin' must be included in the system path
#
# SYNOPSIS
# --------
# Reads the passphrase from '~/keypsph' and stores it in the variable, 'PSPH', then
# calls '/usr/bin/expect' to spawn ssh-add to add the SSH private keys into 
# ssh-agent and provide (send) the passphrase for the keys, followed by a <return>.
#
# '/usr/bin/expect'  can be installed with:
#   sudo apt install expect
#
# Guide:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033799/how-to-make-ssh-add-read-passphrase-from-a-file
#
# Initialize a variable to store an exit code of '0'
EXITCODE=0
#
# Check whether the passphrase file, 'keypsph' exists in the user's home directory. 
# If not terminate the script with an appropriate message and error code.
if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/keypsph ]; then
    echo -e "ERROR: Passphrase file not found in $HOME/.ssh\nExiting..."
    exit 1
fi
# Read the passphrase from file, 'keypsph'
PSPH=$(cat ~/.ssh/keypsph)
#
# Call '/usr/bin/expect' to spawn ssh-add to add the SSH private keys to X2 into 
# ssh-agent and provide (send) the passphrase for the keys, followed by a <return>.
expect << EOF
spawn ssh-add "$HOME/.ssh/x1-x2_key"
expect "Enter passphrase for /home/dasaint/.ssh/x1-x2_key:"
send "$PSPH\r"
expect eof
EOF
# Error Handling...
if [[ $EXITCODE != 0 ]]; then
  echo -e "Error adding x1-x2_key to SSH Agent\nExiting..."
  EXITCODE=$?
  exit $EXIITCODE
fi
#
# Read the passphrase from file, 'keypsph'
PSPH=$(cat ~/.ssh/keypsph)
#
# Call '/usr/bin/expect' to spawn ssh-add to add the SSH private keys to X3 into 
# ssh-agent and provide (send) the passphrase for the keys, followed by a <return>.
expect << EOF
spawn ssh-add "$HOME/.ssh/x1-x3_key"
expect "Enter passphrase for /home/dasaint/.ssh/x1-x3_key:"
send "$PSPH\r"
expect eof
EOF
# Error Handling...
if [[ $EXITCODE != 0 ]]; then
  echo -e "Error adding x1-x2_key to SSH Agent\nExiting..."
  EXITCODE=$?
  exit $EXIITCODE
fi
#
# Read the passphrase from file, 'keypsph'
PSPH=$(cat ~/.ssh/keypsph)
#
# Call '/usr/bin/expect' to spawn ssh-add to add the SSH private keys to X4 into 
# ssh-agent and provide (send) the passphrase for the keys, followed by a <return>.
expect << EOF
spawn ssh-add "$HOME/.ssh/x1-x4_key"
expect "Enter passphrase for /home/dasaint/.ssh/x1-x4_key:"
send "$PSPH\r"
expect eof
EOF
# Error Handling...
if [[ $EXITCODE != 0 ]]; then
  echo -e "Error adding x1-x2_key to SSH Agent\nExiting..."
  EXITCODE=$?
  exit $EXIITCODE
fi
#
# Read the passphrase from file, 'keypsph'
PSPH=$(cat ~/.ssh/keypsph)
#
# Call '/usr/bin/expect' to spawn ssh-add to add the SSH private keys to X8 into 
# ssh-agent and provide (send) the passphrase for the keys, followed by a <return>.
expect << EOF
spawn ssh-add "$HOME/.ssh/x1-x8_key"
expect "Enter passphrase for /home/dasaint/.ssh/x1-x8_key:"
send "$PSPH\r"
expect eof
EOF
# Error Handling...
if [[ $EXITCODE != 0 ]]; then
  echo -e "Error adding x1-x2_key to SSH Agent\nExiting..."
  EXITCODE=$?
  exit $EXIITCODE
fi
#
# Exit the script with the appropriate exit code
exit $EXITCODE
```

I have searched the internet for answers but no one seems to have a comparable issue. I am at my wits end and I could really use some advice.

**PS:**

If I log in as `root` using `su -` and run `rescanscsi` without the absolute path, it also runs just fine.

Comment: See [Have a command in my $PATH, but it is not being recognized when I use sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318179/have-a-command-in-my-path-but-it-is-not-being-recognized-when-i-use-sudo)

Comment: Are you sure that `sudo` is invoking the copy of the `ssh-load-ssh-keys` command that's in `/usr/local/bin/custom` and not a copy that's in another location?

Comment: @steeldriver and Sotto Voce  Yes, that's exactly my issue. did not know that about sudo.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: 'load-ssh-keys' works because I dont need to use it with 'sudo'.  '-E' didn't work and some of the other work-arounds are too cumbersome and inelegant for my taste.  was gonna alter the 'secure_path' in 'sudoers' but since it is a security feature of sudo, I wont mess with it.  Decided to instead use a system-wide alias specifying the absolute path.  Thanks a lot guys.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'user1794469' instead of 'Sotto Voce' in my previous comment but I still do appreciate the tip from Sotto Voce. Althouth I'm sure there are no more copies of 'load-ssh-keys' in my filesystem that's one more trap I know to look out for in future.  Thanks to all of you.
'